# How can we access oauth2 access token from springboot server using angular2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, angular2-security

I've configured authorization server as
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {

```
    clients.inMemory()
            .withClient("clientID")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client-credentials", "password","refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
            .scopes("read", "write", "trust")
            .resourceIds("oauth2-resource")
            .accessTokenValiditySeconds(120)
            .refreshTokenValiditySeconds(300)
            .secret("secret");

}
```

So, based on this configuration, How can I get access_token from angular2 app?

Answer (score 0):

Using `client_credentials` mode fetch the `access_token` from endpoint `/oauth/token` (if you are using the default).

HTTP POST Parameters:

- grant_type: `client_credentials`
- client_id: `clientID`(from your config)
- client_secret: `secret`(from your config)

Response result like this:

```
{
    "access_token": "token...",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "expires_in": 43199,
    "scope": "read write trust",
    "jti": "da2969c9-36e1-4177-b85e-71ed4217a036"
}
```

Configuration of client (extends by `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`):

```
@Override
public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
    security.allowFormAuthenticationForClients();
}
```

**Suggest:**

If you want user login, please consider the `password` grant mode.

Also see RFC6749 [client_credentials](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4)

Comment: thanks for your help @alex  I'm still having trouble. I am using password grant mode. I think I should put clientId and secret in header with base64 encode.